# FutureWarning: pd.expanding_mean is deprecated. What are the alternatives?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
X = np.linspace(-2, 2, 5)
A = pd.expanding_mean(X)
```

> FutureWarning: pd.expanding_mean is deprecated for ndarrays and will
>   be removed in a future version

What do you suggest to use instead of `expanding_mean` and why it would become deprecated?

Comment: are you trying to do [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) kind of expanding? this expanding is using a dataframe, but you don't seem to be using a dataframe in your example

Comment: Could you include the output that you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas, since 1.3.0, [expanding window calculations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) are performed like this:

With your example vector as a pandas series:

```
pd.Series(X).expanding().mean()

0   -2.0
1   -1.5
2   -1.0
3   -0.5
4    0.0
dtype: float64
```

For example, requesting an increasing number of prior rows to allow the operation:

```
pd.concat([pd.Series(X).expanding(i).mean() for i in range(6)], axis=1)

     0    1    2    3    4    5
0 -2.0 -2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1 -1.5 -1.5 -1.5  NaN  NaN  NaN
2 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0  NaN  NaN
3 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5 -0.5  NaN
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

A likely reason for the deprecation of `.expanding_mean()` is that the `expanding` window may be used for a variety of functions, not only `mean`, so it made sense to factorize that part. All functions now available are listed here: [Window](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/window.html)